# How to access OSX NSApplication from StoryBoard created default ViewController?

Tags: macos, reference, nsviewcontroller, nsapplication

I’ve used Xcode 6.3 to create a very simple Swift Mac application. It is not a document-based app. My app has one NSViewController, and it  loads, opens and runs as expected. However, now I need to use the Application menu, and I don’t see the proper way for my NSViewController to communicate with the NSApplicationDelegate or the NSApplication itself.

I am looking for some chain of properties or methods I can call from my NSViewController, after it has loaded, but before it is displayed.

Comment: Is it the global function NSApp? Seems like it...
Ah, the magic of finding the answer right after posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myApplication = NSApp as! NSApplication
    let myAppDelegate = myApplication.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

Works as expected within NSViewController instance.